# MySQL geospatial data (POINT) and JPA in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans, geospatial

I need to just fetch some geospatial data (simple coordinates - POINTS) from MySQL db and use them in Java (NetBeans project). This is what I did so far:

Created MySQL db with following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lokacija` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I also created NetBeans project and set up JPA and everything, added hibernate-spatial library to it and here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="testGisPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.Test</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/dipl?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

After that, created entity and besides all other properties, it also contains following:

```
    ...
    @Column(name = "lokacija")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private Point lokacija;

    @Column(name = "info")
    private String info;
    ...
```

I also generated REST facade directly from NetBeans and I tried to print all items I fetch from the db (currently I have only two items with descriptions "first" and "second" and locations (1,1)) and here is what I get:

```
LOCATION: null
INFO: first

LOCATION: null
INFO: second
```

Any suggestions what else I should do in order to make this work?

Comment: can you please share the code that print `LOCATION: null` ?

Comment: System.out.println("LOCATION: " + item.getLokacija());